# Convergence of sequence of functions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x^4)^n$

On the interval $[0, 1]$ Does this function converge pointwise and if so does it converge uniformly or almost uniformly?

At $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$.

Now, $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x^4)^n = (x(1-x^4))^n = (x - x^5)^n$

If we fix $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$ then both $x^n$ and $(1-x^4)^n$ go to $0$ as $n$ becomes large so we have pointwise convergence to the zero function.

I am unsure of how to determine if the convergence is uniform or not though?

Comment: Hint: Dini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(x) = x - x^5$; this is non-negative for $0 \le x \le 1$, and its derivative is

$$g'(x) = 1 - 5x^4$$

so the function is maximized at $x = 1/\sqrt[4]{5}$ and the maximum is strictly less than $1$. Call the maximum $r$. Then for all $x \in [0, 1]$,

$$|f_n(x) - 0| = |g(x)|^n \le r^n$$

This bound tends to $0$ as $n$ grows, and the bound is uniform in $x$. Hence the convergence is uniform.